# How do I configure Eclipse web browser/network settings?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-wtp, proxy-server

I use an "anonproxy" to bypass network restrictions in some public networks, and somehow eclipse managed to configure itself to use it. Even after I disabled the proxy settings in firefox, eclipse still uses it. When I try to stop the proxy service, eclipse simply pops a message saying the proxy refused connections. How do I remove any proxy settings from eclipse??

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking about the proxy Eclipse uses to access the web, it's in:

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections
```

Comment: This seems to be proxy settings, but no matter what I did with those options, it didnt seem to affect eclipse internal browser